# Load Test option disappeared

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, load-testing

In a Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 *Web Performance and Load Test Project*, I have lost the ability to add a *Load Test*. The option is usually right below *Unit Test...*

[image: Missing Load Test]

---

Instructions to create a *Load Test*:

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/test/performance-testing/run-performance-tests-app-before-release#create-a-load-test

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution in vs 2017 installer.  Apparently not all parts are installed.  If you want to install web performance test template project:

1. run vs 2017 installer
2. go to Individual components -> Debugging & testing
3. select Web performance and load testing tools

[image]

Comment: I can't find it in the Debugging and testing section. Is it available for the professional version? (I have vs2017 professional)

Comment: Also not available on VS 2017 Community. Perhaps it's only available on Enterprise? Official article [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/quickstart-create-a-load-test-project?view=vs-2017).

Comment: Also not available on VS 2019 Professional, but on VS 2019 Enterprise.

Answer (score 1):

Repairing Visual Studio solved the problem. I am not sure what caused it in the first place